# GADInterstitial custom ads not working

Tags: iphone, xcode4.3

i have a problem in getting the GADInterstitial custom ads i have tried this code

```
if(nil != m_pBannerView)
{
    m_pBannerView.delegate = nil;
    [m_pBannerView release];
    m_pBannerView = nil;
}
m_pBannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner];
m_pBannerView.delegate = self;
m_pBannerView.rootViewController = self;
m_pBannerView.adUnitID = @"AdMob Publisher ID";
m_pBannerView.rootViewController = self;
[self.view addSubview:m_pBannerView];

GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
request.testing = YES;
[m_pBannerView loadRequest:request];

if(nil != m_pInterstitial)
{
    [m_pInterstitial release];
    m_pInterstitial = nil;
}

m_pInterstitial = [[GADInterstitial alloc] init];
m_pInterstitial.delegate = self;
m_pInterstitial.adUnitID = @"INTERSTITIAL_AD_UNIT_ID";

GADRequest *interstialRequest = [GADRequest request];
interstialRequest.testing = YES;
[m_pInterstitial loadRequest: interstialRequest];
```

}
And in GADInterstitial Delegates i am calling [ad presentFromRootViewController:self];

but still i am not able to get the custom ads please help me.

Comment: I have the same problem, using the loadAndDisplayRequest: usingWindow: initialImage: described [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/ios/advanced)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use your own unique `id` for `adUnitID` property

Comment: To improve the quality of your post, please include how/why this code will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**GADInterstitial** is an interesting way to show ads in your Apps, and kind of a tricky one too. Following this [example](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-ios-examples/tree/master/admob/InterstitialExample), lets pursue the following steps:

- **First we need to set up the environment for them to show at all.
  Download the [GoogleAdMobAdsSdkiOS](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/download#downloadios), preferably the latest. Add
  the SDK to your project, but do remember to delete the example
  Projects in the AddOns folder in the SDK.**
- **Next, add the following frameworks in your Project>>Build
  Phases>>Link Binary With Libraries:**

  - AdSupport.framework (select Optional if catering for < iOS7)
  - StoreKit.framework
  - CoreData.framework
  - CoreAudio.framework
  - AVFoundation.framework
  - MessageUI.framework
  - AudioTool.framework
  - libGoogleAdMobAds.a (placed in the SDK folder)
- **The basics are complete. Now we need to select the ViewController we wish to see our Ads in. So here's some code, here we import the header for GADInterstitialDelegate and extend it with our MainViewController.h:**

> ```
>    #import "GADInterstitialDelegate.h"
>    #define kSampleAdUnitID @"/6253334/dfp_example_ad/interstitial"
>
>    @class GADInterstitial;
>    @class GADRequest;
>
>    @interface MainViewController : UIViewController<GADInterstitialDelegate>
>    {   
>          BOOL isLoaded_;   
>          NSTimer *quickie_;
>    }
>
>    @property(nonatomic, strong) GADInterstitial *interstitial;
> ```
>
> ```
>    //Make sure the delegate is handled properly.
> ```

- **Now we need to move to the implementation i.e. in MainViewController.m:**

> ```
>    - (void)viewDidLoad
>    {
>        [super viewDidLoad];
>        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
>
>        // FOLLOW THE CODE BELOW FOR ADMOD INTERESTIAL IMPLEMENTATION
>        [self initializeAds];
>        quickie_ = [[NSTimer alloc] init];
>        quickie_ = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(showAdd) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
>    }
>
>
>    -(void)showAdd
>    {   
>        if(isLoaded_ && [quickie_ isValid])
>        {
>            [quickie_ invalidate];
>            quickie_ = nil;
>            [self.interstitial presentFromRootViewController:self];
>        }
>    }
>
>    - (GADRequest *)request
>    {
>        GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
>        return request;
>    }
>
>    -(void)initializeAds
>    {
>        // Create a new GADInterstitial each time.  A GADInterstitial will only show one request in its
>        // lifetime. The property will release the old one and set the new one.
>        self.interstitial = [[GADInterstitial alloc] init];
>        self.interstitial.delegate = self;
>
>        // Note: kSampleAdUnitId is a staticApId for example purposes. For personal Ads update kSampleAdUnitId with your interstitial ad unit id.
>        self.interstitial.adUnitID = kSampleAdUnitID;
>        [self.interstitial loadRequest:[self request]];
>    }
>
>    - (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
>    {
>        [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
>        self.loadingSpinner.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds) / 2, self.loadingSpinner.center.y);
>    }
>
>    - (void)interstitialDidReceiveAd:(GADInterstitial *)interstitial
>    {
>        isLoaded_ = YES;
>    }
>
>    - (void)interstitial:(GADInterstitial *)interstitial didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(GADRequestError *)error
>    {
>        isLoaded_ = NO;
>    }
>
>    //----ADS IMPLEMENTATION TILL HERE--->//
> ```

The timer "quickie_" here constantly checks if the Ad has successfully loaded and when it does, it shoots the Ad on the ViewController if the user still is on it. The static kSampleAdUnitID is a sampleId that always works. Thats it. Run your code and find your Interstitial Ad on your ViewController of choice.
Hope I helped. Cheers! :)